# flutter AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin not working in webview

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to persist the state of this widget where I show a webview but each time the widget is reinitialized loosing the state

this it from where I create the widget that came from a switch case giving each time a unique key

```
child: LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (context, constraints) {
                      switch (data.actualModule) {
                        case 'home':
                          return Container();
                        case 'anagrafica':
                          return Container();
                        case 'geoanalisi':
                          return WebPage(
                            key: Key(data.actualModule),
                            mainPageProvider: data,
                            module: data.getGoupedModule(data.actualModule),
                          );
                        default:
                          return Container();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
```

and this is the widget it self

```
class WebPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final MainPageProvider mainPageProvider;
  final MoosaicoModule module;

  const WebPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.mainPageProvider,
    required this.module,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WebPage> createState() => _WebPageState();
}

class _WebPageState extends State<WebPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<WebPage> {
  double progress = 0.0;
  final _controllerWindows = WebviewController();
  InAppWebViewController? _controller;
  PullToRefreshController? _pullToRefreshController;
  bool _isLoading = true;

  BuildContext getContext() {
    return context;
  }

  void _toggleIsLoading(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = value;
    });
  }

  buildElements(MainPageProvider data) {}

  setupPage(MainPageProvider data) async {
    // await data.setupAnagrafica();
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  void initializeWebView() async {
    await _controllerWindows.initialize();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _controllerWindows.loadUrl(Configuration.returnURLServerClienteWebPage(widget.module.relativeUrl!));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    final dataMain = context.watch<MainPageProvider>();
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.0),
      color: ThemeManager.elementBackgroundColor,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 8.0, left: 16.0, right: 8.0),
                  child: MooText(
                    widget.module.module.code.localized(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: ThemeManager.bigFontSize,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (Platform.isWindows) ...[
                MooIconButton(
                  icon: CommunityIcons.chevronLeft,
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controllerWindows.goBack();
                  },
                  buttonState: _isLoading && dataMain.connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none ? MooIconButtonState.disabled : MooIconButtonState.enabled,
                ),
                MooIconButton(
                  icon: CommunityIcons.reload,
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controllerWindows.reload();
                  },
                  buttonState: _isLoading && dataMain.connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none ? MooIconButtonState.disabled : MooIconButtonState.enabled,
                ),
                MooIconButton(
                  icon: CommunityIcons.chevronRight,
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controllerWindows.goForward();
                  },
                  buttonState: _isLoading && dataMain.connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none ? MooIconButtonState.disabled : MooIconButtonState.enabled,
                ),
              ] else ...[
                MooIconButton(
                  icon: CommunityIcons.chevronLeft,
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controller!.goBack();
                  },
                  buttonState: _isLoading && dataMain.connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none ? MooIconButtonState.disabled : MooIconButtonState.enabled,
                ),
                MooIconButton(
                  icon: CommunityIcons.reload,
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controller!.reload();
                  },
                  buttonState: _isLoading && dataMain.connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none ? MooIconButtonState.disabled : MooIconButtonState.enabled,
                ),
                MooIconButton(
                  icon: CommunityIcons.chevronRight,
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controller!.goForward();
                  },
                  buttonState: _isLoading && dataMain.connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none ? MooIconButtonState.disabled : MooIconButtonState.enabled,
                ),
              ],
              Flexible(
                child: dataMain.accountWidget,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: dataMain.connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none
                ? Stack(
                    children: [
                      if (Platform.isWindows) ...[
                        StreamBuilder<LoadingState>(
                          stream: _controllerWindows.loadingState,
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data == LoadingState.loading) {
                              _toggleIsLoading(true);
                              return const LinearProgressIndicator();
                            } else {
                              _toggleIsLoading(false);
                              return Webview(_controllerWindows);
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ] else ...[
                        InAppWebView(
                          initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                            url: WebUri(
                              Configuration.returnURLServerClienteWebPage(widget.module.relativeUrl!),
                            ),
                          ),
                          pullToRefreshController: _pullToRefreshController,
                          onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                            _controller = controller;
                          },
                          onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                            _toggleIsLoading(true);
                          },
                          onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
                            setState(() {
                              this.progress = progress / 100;
                            });
                          },
                          onReceivedError: (controller, request, error) {
                            _toggleIsLoading(true);
                          },
                          onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
                            _toggleIsLoading(false);
                          },
                        ),
                        progress < 1.0 ? LinearProgressIndicator(value: progress) : Container(),
                      ],
                    ],
                  )
                : const Center(
                    child: Text('Nessuna connessione'),
                  ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

so I expect to not see the webview reloaded each time but only the first time that the widget is created but maybe I'm missing some concepts

Comment: i think you are creating new webview instead of changing url on state change

Comment: But also if I create only a counter the state is not maintained